# SceneKit Scene Background Contents UIImage Array Error

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift2, scenekit

I am developing a game for iOS using `SceneKit`. When I want to set a skybox to the scene I get an error:

```
var path = "skyboxes.scnassets/skybox"
self.scene!.background.contents = [
        UIImage(named: path+"_right.png"),
        UIImage(named: path+"_left.png"),
        UIImage(named: path+"_top.png"),
        UIImage(named: path+"_bottom.png"),
        UIImage(named: path+"_front.png"),
        UIImage(named: path+"_back.png"),
    ]
```

> Error: Cannot assign a value of type [UIImage?] to a value of type
>   AnyObject!

I tried to cast the array to a `NSArray` or an `AnyObject` array but that doesn't work.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contents` is of type `[AnyObject!]`; so, the following should work:

```
scene!.background.contents =
[
    UIImage(named: path+"_right.png") as UIImage!              
    UIImage(named: path+"_left.png") as UIImage!,
    UIImage(named: path+"_top.png") as UIImage!,
    UIImage(named: path+"_bottom.png") as UIImage!,
    UIImage(named: path+"_front.png") as UIImage!,
    UIImage(named: path+"_back.png") as UIImage!,
]
```